nginx traffic redirect based on subdomain
I am currently attempting to setup my VPS to host multiple different docker containers.
My domain name is hosted on Cloudflare (which has a limited amount of available ports).
After doing research, to my understand nginx is the solution to my problem. I can use it to redirect traffic to certain ports of my VPS. My plan was to have different cname records point to different ports of my machine.
Example : portainer.domain.com -> http://localhost:9443 (in this case my portainer panel)
After finding this video, I based my solution on his:
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name portainer.domain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/portainer.domain.com/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/portainer.domain.com/error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9443;
        }
}

I made sure the config was valid and reloaded nginx:
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/portainer.domain.domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx

I made sure that nginx worked when accessing my host name; I get Welcome to nginx!
However when accessing portainer.domain.com, I get This site can't be reached DNS_PROBE_FINSIHED_NXDOMAIN
Additional notes:

ufw is disabled
both my A and CNAME records are proxied through Cloudflare
my A record is @ and points at ip (of my VPS)
my CNAME record is * and points to @
I've tried removing the CNAME record completely to no avail

Is what I am trying to do possible?
